# OpenCL returning -64 upon calling clGetPlatformIDs

Tags: c++, opencl

Edit: The error code is the following

```
CL_INVALID_PROPERTY if context property name in properties is not a 
supported property name, if the value specified for a supported property 
name is not valid, or if the same property name is specified more than once.
However if the extension cl_khr_gl_sharing is enabled, then 
CL_INVALID_PROPERTY is returned if an attribute name other than those listed
in the table for properties above is specified in properties.
```

I'm using MinGW (x86) and the x86 AMD OpenCL libary, the following code returns NULL after the final check:

```
cl_context CreateContext()
{
     cl_int errNum;
     cl_uint numPlatforms;
     cl_platform_id firstPlatformID;
     cl_context context=NULL;
     //Select an OpenCL platform

     errNum=clGetPlatformIDs(1, &firstPlatformID, &numPlatforms);
     if (errNum!=CL_SUCCESS||numPlatforms<=0)
     {
        cerr<<"Failed to find any OpenCL platforms."<<endl;
        return NULL;
     }

     cl_context_properties contextProperties[]=
     {
        CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,
        (cl_context_properties) firstPlatformID,
     };
     context=clCreateContextFromType(contextProperties, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, NULL, NULL, &errNum);
     cout << errNum << endl;
     if (errNum!=CL_SUCCESS)
     {
         cerr<<"Failed to create an OpenCL GPU context, trying CPU."<<endl;
         context=clCreateContextFromType(contextProperties,CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, NULL, NULL, &errNum);

         if (errNum!=CL_SUCCESS)
         {
            cerr<<"Failed to create an OpenCL GPU or CPU context."<<endl;
            return NULL;
         }
     }
     return context;
}
```

It detects 2 platforms as it should (intel cpu, AMD gpu) but can't create a context. The x64 libary does the same thing. Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of [clCreateContext](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateContext.html) you have to terminate the list of cl_context_properties with a zero.

With the following change the code works for me:

```
cl_context_properties contextProperties[] =
{
    CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,
    (cl_context_properties)firstPlatformID, 
    0
};
```